# Python socketserver stuck at receiving data

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I got into a deadlock issue with my simple socketserver/client test. See code

```
import pickle, json, socket, socketserver, threading
class ServerHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        self.message = b''
        socketserver.BaseRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
    def handle(self):
        while True:
            try:
        # STUCK here when data is fully received.
                data = self.request.recv(1024)
        # STUCK end
                if data is not None:
                    if len(data) > 0:
                        self.message += data
                    else:
                        break
                else:
                    break
            except:
                break
        self.request.send(self.message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    address = ('localhost', 10000)
    server = socketserver.TCPServer(address, ParameterHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address

    th = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    th.setDaemon(True)
    th.start()

    # Client
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.connect((ip, port))
    s.settimeout(0.2)

    message = pickle.dumps(json.loads(open('test.json').read()))
    lenSent = s.send(message)

    server.shutdown()
    s.close()
    server.socket.close()
```

From what I can see, my server probably does not know it has received the full data. So the next `self.request.recv()` call gets stuck. But why isn't it an exception? or why can‘t it simply return `None` if no valid data is received?

I try to use `socketserver` to save the trouble of writing a socket server from scratch, but I don't get this module yet.

Comment: Given the description of the problem I think you have a wrong understanding of how `recv` works. It will return `None` only if an error occurred or if the peer closed the connection. It has no idea of where data should end, i.e. if you call `recv` it will wait until data are received or the connection is closed. This means your application has to know when to expect data and only call `recv` in this case. Note also that TCP is a stream and not a  message protocol, i.e. there is no 1:1 match between a `send` on one side and a `recv` by the peer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks! That makes sense. In my case, I'd love to have the client send parameters as JSON to control server-side app. According to your idea, it seems UDP will be better than TCP, if I can fit the entire JSON in one message?

Comment: I don't think that UDP is better than TCP since contrary to TCP UDP does not care if messages gets reordered, get lost, get duplicated etc. TCP is the better way but you should have some application layer messages defined - for example by prefixing each message which its length so that you know how much bytes you need to read.

Comment: `recv` also does not return None, but an empty string when the client closes the connection.  Use `if not data: break` instead of the double `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some corrections to round-trip a `json` message:

```
import json, socket, socketserver, threading

class ServerHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    # handle should return when the server is done with the connection
    def handle(self):
        message = b''
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            if not data:  # b'' when client shuts down writing on socket.
                break
            message += data
        self.request.sendall(message)  # sendall to ensure sending the full message back.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    address = ('localhost', 10000)
    server = socketserver.TCPServer(address, ServerHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address

    th = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    th.setDaemon(True)
    th.start()

    # Client
    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.connect((ip, port))

    # pickle can be exploited to execute code
    message = json.dumps([1,2,3,4]) # returns `str` on Python 3
    lenSent = s.sendall(message.encode()) # encode to `bytes`

    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR) # client has completed sending.

    recvd = b''
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if not data: break # b'' when server closes connection.
        recvd += data
    print(json.loads(recvd))
    s.close()

    server.shutdown()
    server.socket.close()
```